# W 8.1 loading BitmapImage

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, bitmapimage

I'm loading BitmapImage from a url like this;

```
Uri uri = new Uri(item.url, UriKind.Absolute);
ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
Image.Source = imgSource;
```

The code works fine but sometimes takes to much time to load the image, there is a way to detect that the image was loaded to enable a progress control while is loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remarks and example from the [BitmapImage.DownloadProgress event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.downloadprogress.aspx) page on MSDN:

> For cases where the async loading and decoding of a BitmapImage object
>   are long enough to be noticeable to the user, an app can handle
>   DownloadProgress on the source and display a ProgressRing or
>   ProgressBar to indicate the progress state. These might display in the
>   UI region that the image eventually displays in, or somewhere else in
>   the UI. Use DownloadProgressEventArgs.Progress to modify the UI for a
>   ProgressBar.

```
// somewhere in initialization
bitmapImage.DownloadProgress += new EventHandler<DownloadProgressEventArgs>(bi_DownloadProgress);
bitmapImage.ImageOpened += new EventHandler<ExceptionRoutedEventArgs>(bi_ImageOpened);
...
//progressBar is an existing control defined in XAML or extracted from a XAML template

void bi_DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Value = e.Progress;
}
void bi_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```